# Перестройка записей в цикле

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица NAV:

```
ID,  SORT,  NAME
1    1      a
3    2      a
5    3      a
9    4      a
22   5      a
```

Есть две ссылки:
`nav.php?up&id=%s` и `nav.php?down&id=%s`

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии, например, на ссылку UP, поменялся порядок в SORT:
`ID 3` стал `SORT 1`, a `ID 1` – `SORT 2` То есть поменялись значениями: стала выше, а при `down` – наоборот, ниже.

То есть менять местами порядок. Сортировка при выводе идет по SORT

```
if(isset($_GET['up']))
            {
            ... - 1;
            }

if(isset($_GET['down']))
            {
            ... + 1;
            }

$n = 1;

foreach (...)
{
    mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE nav SET SORT = '{$n}' WHERE id = '$ID'");

$n++;
}
```

Comment: А цикл тут при чем?

Comment: Вам нужна при построении страницы сортировка записей в прямом и обратном порядке? Мне кажется вам нужно не сортировку переписывать каждый раз, а добавлять в запросе  `ORDER BY SORT ASC` или `ORDER BY SORT DESC`

Comment: Нет, вывод итак идет по ORDER BY SORT
нужно сдвинуть пункт меню например в право или лево, чтоб он занял место другого пункта меню.

Answer (score 3):

Запрос для UP выглядит так:

```
update nav set sort=@srt+if(id=  $ID  , -1 ,0)
 where id in(
   select id from (
    select id from nav
     where sort  <=  (select @srt:=sort from nav where id=  $ID  )
     order by sort DESC limit 2
   ) A
);
```

Для DOWN `-1` меняется на `1`, `<=` на `>=`, `DESC` на `ASC`. Запрос спокойно работает в случаях, когда в SORT имеются 'дырки'. В случае, если попытаться поднять первый элемент или опустить последний, его sort изменится на -1/+1, другие записи не изменятся. На последующую работу запроса это не скажется. Можно ограничить такие выходы за границы на уровне интерфейса что бы лишний раз не образовывались дырки.

При добавлении новых записей в таблицу надо следить, что бы SORT оставался всегда уникальным. Например добавлять новые записи всегда в конец, а пользователь потом поднимет на нужную позицию. Либо предусматривать вставку в середину со сдвигом всех последующих записей вниз.

Запрос можно кардинально упростить, если на входе будет готовый SORT поднимаемой/опускаемой записи, а не ее id:

```
update nav set sort= $SORT +if(sort= $SORT ,-1,0)
 where sort <= $SORT
 order by sort desc limit 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно обойтись без цикла, достаточно обменять две позиции местами, их нужно сложить и вычесть из них позицию обмениваемой.

Например, для того, чтобы поднять позицию 3 выше, можно воспользоваться запросом

```
UPDATE NAV
SET SORT = 2 + 1 - 2
WHERE SORT IN (1, 2)
```

А что опустить 1 позицию на место позиции 3 можно воспользоваться запросом

```
UPDATE NAV
SET SORT = 2 + 1 - 1
WHERE SORT IN (1, 2)
```

Если вы поднимаете или опускаете значение на одну позицию, тут встает проблема вычисления этой самой предыдущей позиции. Для вычисления значения SORT предыдущей записи можно использовать запрос (тут выглядит надуманно, но если у вас будут разрывы, а позиция не 2, а скажем 10, то не факт что предыдущая величина 9, а скажем не 7)

```
SELECT SORT
FROM NAV
WHERE SORT < 2
ORDER BY SORT DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Для вычисления следующего значения можно использовать запрос вида

```
SELECT SORT
FROM NAV
WHERE SORT > 1
ORDER BY SORT
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: тут еще вот что если удалить -5-----3--------a а потом добавить новую запись -23----6--------a то порядок нарушиться. В SORT будут значения 1,2,4,5,6 тоесть 3 нет вот их нужно перестпоить в правильном порядке 12345